# Spring Data REST with UUID : PersistentEntity does not have an identifier property

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data and the REST starter to provide a repository of Device entities identified by a UUID.

Related artifacts from my pom.xml (using Spring Boot version `1.5.3.RELEASE`)

```
 spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
 spring-boot-starter-data-rest
```

Extract from the `DeviceDB` class (it is actually a wrapper for the database mapping)

```
private Device device;

@Transient
public Device getDevice() {
    return this.device;
}

public void setDevice(Device device) {
    this.device = device;
}

@Id
@Column( columnDefinition = "uuid")
public UUID getId() {
    return this.device.getId();
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.device.setId(id);
}
```

Extract from the `Device` class (using Gson for JSON serialization)

```
@SerializedName(value = "id")
private UUID deviceId;

public UUID getId() {
    return deviceId;
}

public void setId(UUID deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}
```

Here is the repository:

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends CrudRepository<DeviceDB, UUID> { }
```

Using the repository directly (`deviceRepository.save(device)`) works just fine but a POST requests fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity does not have an identifier property!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.IdPropertyIdentifierAccessor.<init>(IdPropertyIdentifierAccessor.java:47) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl$JpaProxyAwareIdentifierAccessor.<init>(JpaPersistentEntityImpl.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl.getIdentifierAccessor(JpaPersistentEntityImpl.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.DefaultSelfLinkProvider.getResourceId(DefaultSelfLinkProvider.java:97) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.DefaultSelfLinkProvider.createSelfLinkFor(DefaultSelfLinkProvider.java:70) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.getSelfLinkFor(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:99) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:76) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toFullResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:67) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.createAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:488) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:272) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

However, the object does provide a valid UUID and the serialization/deserialization appears to be working.

The POST request is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "device": { "id" : "81e033a7-3b13-4581-b6f4-91616781f9ce" }}' localhost:8090/devices
```

Comment: can you show us the post request.

Comment: ok, I added it to the question.

Comment: UUID  is class used? if used Long as identifier then it will work.

Comment: I changed UUID to Long in the repository, the mapped class and the request but no, the same exception appears.

Comment: begs the question, why does Spring Data JPA insist on making its own checks on metadata when the JPA provider is responsible for all of that!

Comment: As far as I understand, it wrapps the information to abstract the actual ORM mapping library away, to provide better error messages and such...?

Comment: and seemingly does it wrong, since there evidently *is* an identifier property :-P

Comment: @mcxme, what do you mean by `this is a wrapper`? What is `this.device` inside `getId` and `setId` methods? Can you add the code for your `Device` class, including is `this.device` in that class?

Comment: OK, I posted more code and differentiated between the the Device class and the DeviceDB class meant for database mapping.